# suppress output <use image.png> [n] for \includegraphics{image.png} via pdflatex

Tags: graphics, pdftex

When using `\includegraphics{image.png}` my pdflatex console is cluttered with the output

```
<use image.png> [n]
```

Where `n` is the number of includes. This is especially annoying, as I use an image in my header. So I get this output for every single page once.

In addition I have some macros, that use several pictures, so every single use produces a lot of ugly output hiding actual interesting warnings.

Any idea how to get rid of this output?

Comment: Just a hint, store the image in a box (`\newsavebox\headerbox\savebox\headerbox{...image...}` and then use `\usebox\headerbox` in the header. Then I should only be included once ;-)

Comment: Or use `pgf` and declare it as a pgf image, see the `pgf` manual.

Comment: @daleif that isn't necessary `\includegraphics` uses pdf object references so should only include each image once if you give the same argument multiple times.

Comment: But it also suppresses the include stuff ;-)

Comment: @daleif but it will mean that the image is actually copied multiple times as the box is copied, so makes bigger pdf than if you use \includegraphics each time.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle So if we also need to measure the image (for adjustments), just save it in a box, measure the box and forget about the box?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
  \includegraphics[quiet...
                   %%%%%
```

Comment: Thoroughly documented feature!

Comment: I tried to find it in the documentation :( All I found was this: http://www.golatex.de/wiki/%5Cincludegraphics. So where to look next for complete documentation?

Comment: @egreg I didn't think to look at the documentation, I looked at the sources saw `\Gin@log` was going to suggest setting that to `\@gobble` when I saw there was an option to do that....

Comment: @Jan this option (which I only found out about just now) is added by the pdftex option to graphicx so it is documented (a bit) in the comments in the file `texmf-dist/tex/latex/pdftex-def/pdftex.def`

Comment: So @egreg’s comment was irony? Ok.

Comment: @Jan Yes, it was! The option is only described in the file `pdftex.def` and it's considered experimental. Heiko Oberdiek added it to the options of `\includegraphics` without even telling it to the maintainer of `graphicx.sty`. ;-)

Comment: When including a PDF image, the `quiet` option removes some of the output, but not all. The log still contains `[pagenumber <file.pdf>]`. I had a look at the code for `graphicx.sty` and `pdftex.def`, but didn't see where that output came from.

Comment: @GeorgesDupéron it comes from pdftex itself, not from a macro package